# Kivy - change button properties in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, kivy

I'm working on a little calculator app just for the fun of it and i am trying to learn Kivy.  Here is screenshot of some of the buttons.

[Buttons added with default color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmhrH.png)

I used a for loop to add the buttons to the grid layout.  Here is the code:

```
    #add number buttons
    nums = [7,8,9,4,5,6,1,2,3,'.',0,'%']
    for num in nums:
        btn = Button(text=str(num))
        self.numbers.add_widget(btn)
```

I want to remove the default color and then change it to my own color choice.  I changed the above code to this:

```
    #add number buttons
    for num in nums:
        btn = Button(text=str(num))
        # Only colors one of the nine buttons - not sure why!
        #Remove the default color
        btn.background_disabled_normal = ''
        #Add the color I want
        btn.background_color = (0,1,(13/255))
        self.numbers.add_widget(btn)
```

Here is screen shot of the results:

[Buttons after trying to change the color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HpTw.png)

I guess I thought that it would execute the two new lines of code every time it goes through the loop but it does not.  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change:

```
btn.background_disabled_normal = ''
```

to:

```
btn.background_normal = ''
```

and change:

```
btn.background_color = (0,1,(13/255))
```

to:

```
btn.background_color = (0,1,(13/255),1)
```